# Whatever happened to PerlScript?

Tags: perl, vbscript, activestate

My [ActivePerl documentation](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.8/Components/Windows/PerlScript.html) has a section dedicated to this seemingly little-known technology.

I guess that the technology didn't really catch on.

A couple of questions:

- where would PerlScript be useful as a drop-in replacement for an equivalent technology like VBScript?
- does anyone know of any examples where businesses have employed PerlScript?

Comment: I realized the subjective nature of some of my questions and have subsequently removed them

Comment: My guess is that PerScript is/was an ASP technology, and everyone (using MS) has gone to ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveState implemented this for Microsoft IIS, allowing Perl to be used in lieu of VBScript or JScript there.  My guess, therefore, is that most Microsoft shops look to Microsoft tools and hence there is limited adoption.

Comment: Do you know of any advantages that PerlScript might have over VBScript/JScript?

Comment: @Zaid : No, sorry I don't know of either (ad|dis)vantages.

Comment: @Zaid - I once used it (long ago) just because I liked Perl better than VBScript or JavaScript. IMO Perl made things easier, and you could use CPAN.

Comment: @runrig : Why don't you post these as answers seeing they address my first question directly. CPAN could be a ***very*** good reason to use PerlScript

Comment: @AlexandrCiornii : Read my comment to runrig